# global-set-key but exclude specific modes

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs23

I am trying to create a new key-bind that will work fine in all modes except for one, where it conflicts with another.  For example:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-S-down>") 'move-line-down)
```

Is there a simple way (without setting it for specific local modes) to make it global excluding a specific mode?

Comment: Is the conflicting mode a major or minor mode? In the latter case, you could put your key binding in a minor mode and ensure that `minor-mode-map-alist` gives the correct precedence.

Comment: Global key bindings *cannot* clobber major or minor mode keybindings. The latter take precedence (minor over major over global). I would avoid referring to a binding as 'global' (and referencing `global-set-key`) if you are not explicitly referring to the global keymap, because it will just confuse matters. Do you actually want to create a binding that takes precedence over all major and minor mode maps (save for one)?

Comment: @Francesco The conflicting key bind is in a major mode.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a function to `after-change-major-mode-hook` that would set the key in the current *local* keymap, except for the specific modes you would like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude one specific mode, you can do the following:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-S-down>") 'move-line-down)
```

to make it globally available, and

```
(define-key KEYMAP (kbd "<C-S-down>") nil)
```

to exclude one mode
where KEYMAP is the name name of the mode, followed by "mode-map" (e.g. ess-mode-map). 
You could also bind the original thing to the key instead of `nil`.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I thought the OP wanted the opposite: disable his own key binding to get back the original mode binding.